# How to render Jpeg2000 (.jp2) to an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, jpeg2000

How to Render **Jpeg2000 (.jp2)** to `ImageView` in Android

I have been working from long time but i couldn't found Appropriate Solution , I found few Names of Rendering image `jp2` image but not able to find reference of it

1. JJ2000
2. JMagic
3. JAI - Java Advanced Imaging

Please Help me out with the solution

Comment: What issue/error you are facing, What have you tried so far

Comment: Android doesn't support this kind of (ever so rarely used) images.

Comment: thanks @AkshayPaliwal  i have solved using jj2000-android

Comment: thanks @KlingKlang i have solved using jj2000-android

Answer (score 2):

I have Found Solution Using JJ2000

Many other libraries are using AWT code or NDK files i think this is the simpler way to render JP2 to imageView

Reference urls ::

1. https://bitbucket.org/jchauhan/jj2000-android
2. https://github.com/soft-studio/NFC_DriversLicenseReader

Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

You can use Gemalto's [JP2 for Android](https://github.com/gemalto/JP2ForAndroid) library, based on [OpenJPEG](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg).

Add the dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.gemalto.jp2:jp2-android:1.0'
```

and use the following code to convert the JJ2000 bytes to an Android bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new JP2Decoder(jj2000Bytes).decode();
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```